# Fix for sagging gate hitting concrete

Tags: concrete, fence, gates

We have this gate that was installed by the prior owners of the house. It is sagging at the latch side and bottoms out on the concrete.

It seems to me that I need to do a couple things to fix this:

1. Add a brace to the gate from bottom hinge to top latch. That should help with future sag.
2. Level the concrete pad a bit.
3. ???

It looks like the hinges weren't put on straight either so it has a natural lean to it. Is it possible to rehang this with the old and new holes being so close together?

Are there any other recommendations?

[image: Sagging on the right]
[image: Bottoming out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [Anti Sag Gate Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EALTVM8).

Installing this will help to pull the corner up but i would rebuild the bottom rail of this gate first.

I would remove the gate from the fence and place it on a flat work surface, loosen up  or remove the screws holding the main frame rails together and use a square to square it up, then use a [gate hardware kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UTQA10O) to put it all back together (  *i would probably still use the cable kit for added support and adjustablity*. )

Comment: I agree , the best way to repair ( or build) a gate is with a cable and turnbuckle to adjust the dimensions. Chances are you will need to retension with the turnbuckle in the future.